# Cannot broadcast message to specific room? TypeError: Cannot call method 'in' of undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am pretty new to socket.io. I try to send a message between client and server by using socket.io. I want the server to broadcast the message to a specific room but I am not success to do so. The error is that " **Missing error handler on `socket`. TypeError: Cannot call method 'in' of undefined**". I try to simplify my code so to just input room ID like in the following code, room of **123** but I still got the same error.

Server side's code:

```
//For checking the username and display registered user
client.on("join",function(name){
    clients.push(client); 
    console.log("Join Event Successfully");
});

//Create Room on server side
client.on("createRoom", function(name) {
    console.log(name);
    client.join(name); 
    console.log("Room Create Successfully");
    console.log("Room "+ name);
    console.log("Room create successfully");
});

//Join room event

client.on("joinRoom",function(room_id){
    client.join(room_id); 
    console.log("Room Join Successfully");
});

//Socket uses to sync video in real time
//On playing event from one client and need to brocast inside the room
client.on("onPlay",function(data){
    io.to('123').emit("onPlay_server",data);
    console.log("onPlay event trigger");
});

//Socket uses to sync video in real time
//On Pause event from one client and need to brocast inside the room
client.on("onPuase",function(data){
    io.to('123').emit("onPuase_server",data);
    console.log("onPause event trigger");
});
// Event trigger when client disconnect from the sever
client.on("disconnect", function() {  
        console.log("There is someone left the room"+ toString(client.id));
});
```

Client's side code:

```
socketIO.on("onPause_server", function(currentTime){
            console.log("onPause_server");
            if(player_state === 'play'){
              console.log("onPause_server");
              player.pauseVideo();
              Player.seektTo(currentTime);
              player_state = 'pause'
            }
            Player.seektTo(currentTime);
          });
          //Get message from sever side on play message
socketIO.on("onPlay_server", function(currentTime){
            console.log("onPlay_server event trigger");
            if(player_state === 'pause'){
              console.log("onPlay_server event trigger");
              player.seekTo(currentTime);
              Player.playVideo();
              Player_state = "play";
            }
            player.seekTo(currentTime);
          });
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

              //console.log(player.getCurrentTime());
              if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {

                  player.pauseVideo();
                  var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                  player.seekTo(currentTime);   
                  socketIO.emit("onPause",currentTime);
                  player_state = "paused";
              }

              else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  player.playVideo();
                  var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                  socketIO.emit("onPlay",currentTime);
                  player_state = "play";

              }
          }
```

The code is running fine until when client tries to send the message "onPlay" or "onPause" to the server side, the server immediately yields the error of " **Missing error handler on `socket`. TypeError: Cannot call method 'in' of undefined**"

Comment: I have no idea what `brocast` is, but try `client.in('123').emit(...)` (or `client.to('123').emit(...)`), as [per the documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#to(room:string):socket). Also, in your server you misspelled `onPuase` a few times.

Comment: If you refer to this document, http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/, I work according to that one. For misspelled part, I think it is not a problem there but thank you for notice that. I try to use io.to('123') instead of using broadcast but it is still not working.

Comment: There's no mention of `"brocast"` anywhere on that page.

Comment: If you going to default room, you will see it

Comment: That says `"broadcast"`, not `"brocast"`.

Comment: Oh yes, that is a misspelling problem. Let me check on that.

Comment: I have a question on how to use io.to('some room').emit('some event'). If I want to use that one, is it possible if I replace the above code with io.to('123').emit('some event') let say all client when they request to join room, I call it this way client.join('123').

Comment: I update the code in the question a little bit I think I omit it last time make it difficult for you to understand what I want to do. So  I add it. I try to make sure that when the server broadcast the message to all client, all client in that room will get it but I try to print in the console but it didn't print anything but server-side get the message correctly.

Comment: I don't understand why it not working. I don't know whether server is not broadcasting the message or client is not getting it. Do you have any solution on how to keep track on those messages communication? If so, it would be really awesome.